# SQL : list differences between rows (showed in columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

I have a table like this

```
ID   |  FatherID     |   A   |  B    |   C   |     D        | ...
1234 |     -1        |  John | Doe   |   15  |   20181211   | ...
5678 |     -1        |  Mark | Bloch |   34  |   20170804   | ...
4554 |     1234      |  John | Dee   |   25  |   20181211   | ...
2457 |     5678      |  Chris| Bloch |   34  |   20180402   | ...
```

If a modification is done one a given object (eg ID 1234), the system stores the new version data on a new ID (eg 4554) with a reference to the original ID (FatherID = 1234).
The system only stores the initial version and the head revision (last modification), eg if 4554 is eventually modified again, no new record would be created but 4554 values would be updated --> Max 2 records per ID

There are lots of columns (around 400) ...

I'd like to list the modifications that have been done in a format like that :

```
ID   | Field | Before       | After
4554 |  B    | Doe          | Dee
4554 |  C    | 15           | 25
2457 |  A    | Mark         | Chris
4554 |  D    | 20170804     | 20180402
```

and I am struggling to do that especially given the number of columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Sybase?

Comment: Hi jarlh, the sytem can be deployed both on Sybase and Oracle but I can focus on Sybase to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could unpivot paired columns and filter only different.

```
select id, fatherid, field, o before, n after 
  from (
    select n.id, n.fatherid, n.a na, o.a oa, n.b nb, o.b ob, 
           to_char(n.c) nc, to_char(o.c) oc, 
           to_char(n.d) nd, to_char(o.d) od
      from t n join t o on n.fatherid = o.id)
  unpivot ((n, o) for field in ((na, oa) as 'A', (nb, ob) as 'B', 
                                (nc, oc) as 'C', (nd, od) as 'D'))
  where n <> o or (n is null and o is not null) or (n is not null and o is null)
  order by id, field
```

**<sup>[demo with your sample data](https://rextester.com/OTPFA87494)</sup>**

```
    ID   FATHERID  FIELD  BEFORE    AFTER
------  ---------  -----  --------  -----------
  2457       5678  A      Mark      Chris
  2457       5678  D      20170804  20180402
  4554       1234  B      Doe       Dee
  4554       1234  C      15        25
```

You have to list all columns, convert them to chars. Much work, much space for errors, but that's the best I've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

> There are lots of columns (around 400) ...

Just to give you an idea how it is with only 4 columns checked (this is for Oracle):

```
WITH full AS (
  SELECT 
    o.ID, 
    o.A, o.B, o.C, o.D, 
    n.A AS newA, n.B AS newB, n.C AS newC, n.D AS newD 
  FROM tablename o 
  INNER JOIN tablename n ON n.FatherID = o.ID
  WHERE o.FatherID = -1
)

SELECT ID, Field, Before, After FROM(
  SELECT 
    ID,
    'A' As Field,
    CASE WHEN A <> newA THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS changed,
    A AS Before,
    newA AS After
  FROM full
  UNION
  SELECT 
    ID,
    'B' As Field,
    CASE WHEN B <> newB THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS changed,
    B AS Before,
    newB AS After
  FROM full
  UNION
  SELECT 
    ID,
    'C' As Field,
    CASE WHEN C <> newC THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS changed,
    C AS Before,
    newC AS After
  FROM full
  UNION
  SELECT 
    ID,
    'D' As Field,
    CASE WHEN D <> newD THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS changed,
    D AS Before,
    newD AS After
  FROM full
)  
WHERE changed = 1
```